# duplicate key value violates unique constraint "photo_photo_user_id_key" DETAIL: Key (user_id)=(102) already exists

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I receive the error above whenever users want to change their already existing profile.

This is the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db import transaction
from .models import Photo
from .forms import PhotoForm
```

## Create your views here.

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def upload(request, pk=None):
    instance = Photo.objects.get(pk=pk) if pk else None
    context = dict(save_pk=pk or "")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Only backend upload should be posting here
        context['backend_form'] = form = PhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Uploads image and creates a model instance for it
            context['posted'] = form.save(commit=False)
            context['posted'].user = request.user
            context['posted'].save()

        instance = Photo.objects.get(pk=pk) if pk else None
    else:
        # Form demonstrating backend upload
        context['backend_form'] = PhotoForm(instance=instance)

    return render(request, 'photo/upload.html', context)
```

from the stack trace, the problem is coming from this line

```
context['posted'].save()
```

How do I go about it? I want the users to be able to change their profiles without trying to create a new instance afresh.

This is the HTML template

```
<main class="mt-5 pt-5 container">
  <!--A standard form for sending the image data to your server -->
  <div class="mt-5 pt-5 container bg-white">
    <h3 class="text-center">Upload</h3>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="mb-auto p-2 bd-highlight">
          <form action="{% url 'upload' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="text-center mt-5 ">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ backend_form }}
        </div>
        <div class="p-2 bd-highlight text-center">    
          <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="text-center xbtn btn btn-primary">
        </div>  
    </form>
    </div>
    {% if posted %}
      <div class="results">
        {% if posted.errors %}
          Errors: {{ posted.errors }}
        {% else %}
          <div class="uploaded_info">
            <div class="img-responsive">
              {% cloudinary posted.image THUMBNAIL %}
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>


</main>
  
<footer class="footerofupload">
{% block footer %} {% include 'footer-min.html' %} {% endblock footer %}
</footer>


models.py
from django.db import models
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField
from xpro.models import User
# Create your models here.


class Photo(models.Model):
    # Misc Django Fields
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='photo')
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField("Title (optional)", max_length=150, blank=True)

    # Points to a Cloudinary image
    image = CloudinaryField('image')

    """ Informative name for mode """
    def __unicode__(self):
        try:
            public_id = self.image.public_id
        except AttributeError:
            public_id = ''
        return "Photo <%s:%s>" % (self.title, public_id)
```

Below is the user model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('O', 'Other'),
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )

    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_school = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_sponsor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='O')
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, editable=False)
    # avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/avarta', blank=True, default= '/media/avarta/default.png', null=True,)
```

Comment: You should show your models for this. Anyway I assume you have set `unique=True` on the `ForeignKey` to `user` or perhaps you have a `OneToOneField` with `user`.

Comment: I have added the models. Kindly check

Comment: Not your user model check your `Photo` model.

Comment: The Photo Model was the first thing I added. Please check it. It's on the same page with the HTML template. My bad, pardon me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `OneToOneField` between `User` and `Photo` as here:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='photo')
```

This essentially means for one User there can only be one Photo (and vice-versa). If you want multiple photos for one user change it to a `ForeignKey`:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='photos')
```

If you want only one photo for a user delete any previous photos before adding any new one:

```
Photo.objects.filter(user=request.user).delete()
context['posted'] = form.save(commit=False)
```